# Error while using np.sum and functions in python

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I am trying to calculate an integral as a summation of points. This is the important part of my code:

I define an array:

```
x = np.arange(-3,3,0.0223)
```

For this array I want to define a function shell_charge that sums the values of the bits inside of a shell that I define as r <= x

```
def piecew(x):
    inside_shell = np.where(r <= x)
    shell_charge = np.sum(dq[inside_shell])
```

^^ this is what I am trying to understand and fix

```
    conds = [x == 0, (x >= -0.5) & (x <= 0.5), (x > 0.5) & (x < -0.5)]
    funcs = [lambda x: 0.0, lambda x: k * shell_charge * (x)**-2, 
        lambda x: k * total_charge * (x+0.5)**-2.]
    return np.piecewise(x, conds, funcs)

xx = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)

plt.plot(xx,piecew(xx))
plt.title("electric field along the x-axis")
plt.xlabel("x position [m]")
plt.ylabel("mag(E) [N/C]")
plt.show()
```

I am very new to working with arrays and I am not sure how to do this, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: The title says "Error while using np.sum...".  Please include the complete traceback (i.e. error message) in the question.

Comment: What are the shapes of `dq`, `r` and `x`?